# Why is count(id) resulting 3 dimensional array?

Tags: mysql, cakephp

Im using this direct query method in cakephp to get a count (against the norms of MVC).

```
$count = $this->History->query("SELECT count(id) AS x FROM ratings WHERE id='3' AND employee='28'");
```

But it turns out that, i need to use `$count[0][0]['x']` to get the value.

Why isnt it available at `$count['x']`?

Comment: you can use cakes find method here - you just won't. that's a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, its because the function

```
$this->History->query(....);
```

does not return a single dimensional array. I will suggest you to create a `helper function`, which extracts the single dimensional array and return it.

```
function single_query($query) {
    $result = $this->History->query($query);
    return $result[0][0];
}
```

then use it

```
$count = $this->single_query("SELECT count(id) AS x FROM ratings WHERE id='3' AND employee='28'");
```

Answer (score 1):

in your case it will return it in a general way: 0 = iterate over all models, and again 0 since you dont have a specific model name). your result will always be in `$count[0][0]['fieldname']` then.
it is highly recommended to always use the wrapper methods if possible.

why are you not using the cakephp database wrapper methods as documented?

```
$count = $this->History->find('count', array('conditions'=>array('id'=>3, 'employee'=>28));
```

?

it would result in the expected output `x`

Comment: As you can see im using direct query method. In my particular case i cannot make use of cake's find method.

Comment: then you have to live with it or wrap it in your model (to return the integer only).

Comment: Why are you querying rating table from History model? Do you not have a Rating model? Are History and Rating related in any way?

Comment: I didnt even spot that he queries ratings from the history model. even worse. no wonder he needs query() here. so to sum it up: `$this->History->Rating->find('count')` then and a hasMany relation your History Model should make it work.